# How can I know when the scope changes within an abstract syntax tree?

Tags: javascript, scope, abstract-syntax-tree, esprima

Can someone help me with figuring out how to know when the scope changing while traversing the ast tree? I am using the esprima parser and I know that babel does this but I want to create my own to understand how it works and help increase my knowledge with using asts.

So how would I go about to knowing the scopes of each node?

```
var global = "I am in the global scope";

function scopeOne() {
  var one = "I am in the scope created by `scopeOne()`";

  function scopeTwo() {
    var two = "I am in the scope created by `scopeTwo()`";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base idea is to determine how many scopes is upper then current node. For this purpose we need to check:

- is current node is `Program`, the upper most node in `AST`;
- is current node is `BlockStatements` that is used by all kinds of functions and statements (like `IfConditionStatement`, loops etc);

Then we just increase counter of scopes, this way we can distinguish them in the similar to `Babel` way.

Here is how it can look like written in [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiserputout), tool I'm working on:

```js
export const traverse = () => {
    let uid = 0;
    return {
        'BlockStatement|Program'(path) {
            console.log('babel scope', path.scope.uid);
            console.log('our scope', ++uid);
        },
    }
};
```

For code like this:

```js
var global = "I am in the global scope";

function scopeOne() {
  var one = "I am in the scope created by `scopeOne()`";

  function scopeTwo() {
    var two = "I am in the scope created by `scopeTwo()`";
  }
}

if (a > 3) {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

It outputs:

[image: Scopes]

Playground: https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/06b547b6cd6f132b5300dd9d4473177e/b2a193c5c7233c309c46222cbb9ea8a46bd99a92